# DuplicateKey Exception while trying to run the batch job on multiple Instances

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-scheduled

I am running a batch job in a cluster at the same time with the same parameters. Though, its fine that it is running only on one instance but the exception I am getting is:

```
Detail: Key (job_name, job_key)=(offlineTicketRefreshJob, c5d36835a13fd8ae0e91a69a6fa1c2d8) already exists.; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "job_inst_un"
```

I was expecting that it will give JobAlreadyRunningException or the other. I think the isolation level is also serializable for batch job repository so why is it giving PSQLException?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should not happen if you correctly configure the isolation level on your job repository. You did not share your job repository configuration but you can find an example int the [Configuring a JobRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/job.html#configuringJobRepository) and [Transaction Configuration for the JobRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/job.html#txConfigForJobRepository) sections:

```
// This would reside in your BatchConfigurer implementation
@Override
protected JobRepository createJobRepository() throws Exception {
   JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
   factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
   factory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
   factory.setIsolationLevelForCreate("ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE");
   factory.setTablePrefix("BATCH_");
   factory.setMaxVarCharLength(1000);
   return factory.getObject();
}
```

An aggressive isolation level prevents creating duplicate job instances in a clustered environment. `SERIALIZABLE` and `READ_COMMITTED` should work.

Comment: Isn't the default isolation is SERIALIZABLE as stated in the same documentation so I didnt configure the jobrepository and used the default.

Comment: yes, `SERIALIZABLE` is the default and postgres supports it (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/transaction-iso.html). Which version of postgres are yo using?

Comment: I am using 12.0

Comment: Debugged the code, looks like it is setting ISOLATION_DEFAULT as isolation level which is read_committed in postgres. Tried configuring jobrepository as mentioned but it is giving issues as I am using JPAItemWriter for writing items which says "TransactionRequiredException", no transaction in progress.

Comment: The default is SERIALIZABLE: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/d8fc58338d3b059b67b5f777adc132d2564d7402/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/support/AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.java#L62. You should be overriding it somewhere if you have ISOLATION_DEFAULT when debugging. Now that's fixed, for JPAItemWriter to work, you need to make sure Spring Batch is configured with a JpaTransactionManager, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22509529

Comment: One more question, If I don't configure the repository. Then there is no TransactionRequiredException. It should have been same thing for that.. right?

Comment: I am getting TransactionRequired at other places now as well.. apart from batch