# not able to save data in Spring batch JPA

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-batch

Getting below error if i try to save the data in MYSql DB in spring batch .

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: no transaction is in progress; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:403) ~[spring-orm-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:257) ~[spring-orm-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528) ~[spring-orm-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153) ~[spring-tx-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Think you're simply missing `@Transactional` anywhere on your public method. Therefore no SQL transaction is present given the current context.

Comment: Where should i put @transactional in batch??

Comment: and also my db save code is in reader of spring batch

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JpaItemWriter: no transaction is in progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22509529/jpaitemwriter-no-transaction-is-in-progress)